# Oracle Patch 19.17 fails with: patch 34086870: Archive::Zip->writeToFileNamed returned 4

Tags: oracle, oracle-19c, patching

The current oracle patch 19.17 and OJVM was applied with opatch apply successfully with no errors.

- Patch 34468114: WINDOWS DATABASE BUNDLE PATCH 19.17.0.0.221018
- Patch 34411846: OJVM RELEASE UPDATE 19.17.0.0.0

The datapatch fails with the follwoing error. How to solve this?

```
 D:\oracle\product\19000\db\OPatch\datapatch -verbose

...

No interim patches need to be rolled back
Patch 34468114 (Windows Database Bundle Patch : 19.17.0.0.221018 (34468114)):
Apply from 19.16.0.0.0 Release_Update 220717095735 to 19.17.0.0.0 Release_Update 221027022151
The following interim patches will be applied:
34411846 (OJVM RELEASE UPDATE: 19.17.0.0.221018 (34411846))

Error: prereq checks failed!
patch 34086870: Archive::Zip->writeToFileNamed returned 4
Prereq check failed, exiting without installing any patches.

Please refer to MOS Note 1609718.1 and/or the invocation log
D:\oracle\product\19000\db\cfgtoollogs\sqlpatch\sqlpatch_5176_2022_12_02_13_58_27\sqlpatch_invocation.log
for information on how to resolve the above errors.

SQL Patching tool complete on Fri Dec 2 14:01:25 2022
```

Patch 34086870: OJVM RELEASE UPDATE 19.16.0.0.0 seem to be the OJVM patch from the previous quarter.

Answer (score 0):

The only way we found to fix this :

```
delete from DBA_REGISTRY_SQLPATCH where PATCH_ID=34086870;
```

This is not confirmed by oracle support.